# Intellij Content Assist for Scala popup shows subset of available methods?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, content-assist

The screenshot below shows the popup from Content Assist for the methods and attributes of an instance of List.. For some reason only a fraction of the methods available in the given collection class are shown. In the screenshot we see a List: but the same problem occurs for others including ListBuffer, MutableList,etc.

It is not clear what pattern is followed here.  The scala.Any methods are present as well as a selected few of the collections methods ( andThen and compose). But the majority of the collections classes methods are missing.

Is there a setting and/or some workaround to mitigate /fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered the reason: the "instance" is actually only a reference in the code location shown.  So after making it a real instance the code completion does work.

Before:

```
var children  = List[Node[T]]
```

After:

```
var children  = List[Node[T]]()
```

Now I did actually realize the reference had not yet been initialized: but had not considered that IJ needed that to happen before being able to display methods that ALL List's provide.

The screenshot below shows the changes : initialized the instance and popup subsequently behaving as expected.

[image]